# Is it any way we can use the latest json.net library to an Azure function?

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, json.net, azure-functions

I have an Azure Function under .net core 3.1.
In that function I have installed the latest *Newtonsoft.Json* .net library (currently version 13.0.1).

I try to run the function app and in the Startup of it, I have a breakpoint and then i open the *modules* window.

When I search for the Newtonsoft library, I always see that version 12.00.3 is always loaded.

[image]

My project file has the common lines:

```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v3</AzureFunctionsVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
      <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="3.0.13" />
      <PackageReference Include="Newtonsoft.Json" Version="13.0.1" />
      <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http" Version="4.3.4" />
      ...
      ...
  </ItemGroup>
```

I have read somewhere that Azure functions are locking the version of the Newtonsoft library they are using but they say that installing new version via NuGet package manager should do the trick.

In order to ensure that nothing happens on my development environment I even created an Http triggered function that runs on Azure and from it I return the assembly versions:

```
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post", Route = null)] TelematicsMessage req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        var dir = $"{Directory.GetCurrentDirectory()}\\Newtonsoft.Json.dll";
        var vvv = AssemblyName.GetAssemblyName(dir);

        var runtimeVersion = typeof(JsonConvert)
            .GetTypeInfo()
            .Assembly
            .GetCustomAttribute<AssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>();

        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        return new OkObjectResult(runtimeVersion.InformationalVersion + " --- " + vvv.Version.ToString());
    }
```

Running the function I get the following result:

```
12.0.3+<some hex number> --- 12.0.0.0
```

Does anyone know what might be happening?

Comment: The azure function runtime have hard dependencies on some packages. I you try the isolated mode it should work for you.

Comment: Hi @Thomas, you mean running the functions in version .net 5.0 and later, right? Is it any way to do it in .net core 3.1?

Comment: Isolated process only works for .NET Framework 4.8, .NET 5.0 and .NET 6.0 as per documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/dotnet-isolated-process-guide#supported-versions.

Comment: You will need to move away from .net core 3.1 soon as the support ends in december this year: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/extended-support-for-microsoft-net-core-31-will-end-on-3-december-2022/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- *As suggested by @thomas and as per this [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-dotnet-class-library?tabs=v2,cmd). As you have few dependencies on some of your packages it's better if you could try Isolated packages. Which is also easy in using Nuget packages.*
- *If you are using Isolated process, then only `.Net 4.8 5.0 and 6.0` will work you can't use `.Net3.1`*

[image]

- *Also it's better if you upgrade your version from .Net 3.1 as Microsoft is stopping the [support](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/extended-support-for-microsoft-net-core-31-will-end-on-3-december-2022/) this year.*